# How to avoid app being killed when using sdcard that is about to be mounted?

Tags: android, crash, android-sdcard, mount, kill-process

Suppose I have heavy work to do on the SD card (like CRC check, download, or whatever you can think of). As it turns out, if the user, during the runtime of the app mounts the SD card (or removes it), the app will automatically be killed by the OS without any warning.

I want to avoid it, and not to exit. Instead, I would like to stop the work and resume when possible (or do something else, just not being killed).

So , in short , my question is as the title says: **how do i avoid my app being killed while using the sdcard, when the SD card is being mounted ?**

I've tried the following:

1. catch all exceptions . this didn't work since the app is simply killed .
2. listen to the intent of mounting via a broadcastReceiver . didn't work since the app is killed before it catches the intent.
3. check the status of the sd card . this won't work since the mounting can be done between the checking and the writing .

i might be able to create a new service that handles all of the things related to the sd card , and provide it with its own process , but is that really the solution ? will it even work ? isn't there any other way to overcome this problem?

as a sample code , you can use the code below . it's just for solving of the problem :

```
public void createExternalStoragePrivateFile()
{
  final File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");
  try
  {
    final InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    final byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
    {
      os.write(data[i]);
      Log.d("DEBUG", "byte " + i + " out of " + (data.length + 1));
      // try to mount during this loop and avoid crashing/being killed
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
   }
  catch (final IOException e)
  {
    Log.w("DEBUG", "Error writing " + file, e);
  }
  catch (final InterruptedException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

note: of course the app that i develop is installed in the internal storage . i know that it doesn't make sense that an app that is installed on the sd card won't be killed . of course ,it could be an interesting question too (maybe even be able to avoid mounting the sd card?) , but that's not the question here.

Comment: why your app is killed by mounting sd card? it only raise CONFIGURATION_CHANGE in most cases.. of course it will re-create your activity, but should not killing the Application itself.

Comment: have you tried it? try to execute the code i've written in an asyncTask , and while it runs , quickly mount the sd card and return to the app . after a short while , when the sd card has finished being mounted , it will be killed . as i've read on many places (including this website) , that's the way the OS works

Comment: btw, configuration changes has nothing to do with mounting the sd card : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config . maybe you are confusing with the sim card ?

Comment: ok, suppose it is like this, you mean while you are working on sd card and the sd card is removed?

Comment: it can occur when the sd card is either removed or mounted by the computer that is connected to the device .

Comment: Ever make any headway on this?  Having the same problem and can't figure it out.  Debugger catches no exceptions...I just eject the SDcard and boom, the app closes.

Comment: no i never found an answer for this . seems like that even google doesn't want to handle it since their new nexus device doesn't have a real external storage .they even mentioned that it makes headaches for developers to handle special cases of the sd card.

Comment: @android developer:Facing Same problem,If anyone knows please share the solution.